# Changing permalink of default Post with custom post

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

I have created new post type for jobs and i was using the default post for my blogs. Now the issue arisen for the jobs permalink as i was using example.com/blogs/%postname% earlier now i want on jobs is example.com/jobs/%postname% but it is showing up like example.com/blog/%postname%(that is my posted job title)

Answer (score 0):

If you have your permalink structure set up as `/blogs/%postname%` then the post type will assume you want this for new post types as well. You'll need to define rewrites for the `jobs` post type by using the [rewrite rule](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#rewrite).

`'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'jobs', 'with_front' => false)`

Make sure to flush your permalinks afterwards by going to your WordPress dashboard, navigating to Settings -> Permalinks, and clicking "Save Changes".